# Bound Textbox Not Updating on Change in Codebehind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf-binding

I copied this code from another project and can't figure out why it isn't working.  My observable collections are working great binding and updating, but my textboxes aren't changing.  I have a button click that lets the user pick a directory (`DirectoryBrowse()` method) and then assigns that value to the data context's property that is bound to the textbox.  `PropertyChanged` is always null and I can't figure out why!  The initial binding works just fine, just note when I change the value in the code-behind.  I've been at this entirely too long, but any help would be appreciated!

`DataContext` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings : ViewModels.ViewModelEntity
{
    public static Settings defaultSettings { get; set; }

    private string _ExportDir;
    public string ExportDir
    {
        get { return this._ExportDir; }
        set
        {
            if (this._ExportDir != value)
            {
                this._ExportDir = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ExportDir");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _LastRunTime;
    public string LastRunTime
    {
        get { return this._LastRunTime; }
        set
        {
            if (this._LastRunTime != value)
            {
                this._LastRunTime = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("LastRunTime");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _TSCertPath;
    public string TSCertPath
    {
        get { return this._TSCertPath; }
        set
        {
            if (this._TSCertPath != value)
            {
                this._TSCertPath = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("TSCertPath");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Map> Brokers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    public List<Holiday> Holidays { get; set; }
    public bool RefreshHolidays { get; set; }
    public string ProxyServer { get; set; }
    public string ProxyPort { get; set; }
    public string ProxyUsername { get; set; }
    public string ProxyPassword { get; set; }
    public bool TSProd { get; set; }
    public string TSTriad { get; set; }
    public string TSPassword { get; set; }
    public string TSCertPassword { get; set; }

    public Settings()
    {
        this.Brokers = new ObservableCollection<Map>();
        this.Accounts = new ObservableCollection<Account>();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="File Export Path*"/>
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=ExportDir, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button x:Name="btnBrowseExportDir" Content="..." Click="btnBrowseExportDir_Click"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Settings.Initialize();
    this.DataContext = Settings.defaultSettings;

    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

    if (args.Contains("create"))
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private string DirectoryBrowse()
{
    CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
    CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result.ToString().ToUpper() == "OK")
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dialog.FileNames.First()))
        {
            this.lblStatus.Text = "Invalid directory selected";
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return dialog.FileNames.First();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.lblStatus.Text = "Invalid directory selected";
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

private void btnBrowseExportDir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.defaultSettings.ExportDir = DirectoryBrowse();
}
```

`ViewModelEntity`:

```
public class ViewModelEntity
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your ViewModel and the Settings-class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: If you implement `ICommand` you can bind your button the the command in your view model.  Then you can set the textbox binded property directly, instead of setting the textbox text property.

Comment: pls include code for function `Settings.Initialize()`

Comment: Your `ViewModelEntity` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as Dave mentioned.

Comment: @Dave and Icepickle that did the trick.  Thank you so much, I was going nuts and it was late in the day.  Thanks again!  
ps - Settings.Initialize loads a static instance of the settings called default settings.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.defaultSettings` is never assigned a value. So the databinding have nothing to work with.

Thoug code for `Settings.Initialize()` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

@Dave and @Icepickle showed me what I was missing, no implementaiton of INotifyPropertyChanged!